# Prolog Programming

Tags: prolog, n-queens, state-space, beam-search

I have made two programs in Prolog for the nqueens puzzle using hill climbing and beam search algorithms.

Unfortunately I do not have the experience to check whether the programs are correct and I am in dead end.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out on that.
Unfortunately the program in hill climbing is incorrect. `:(`
The program in beam search is:

```
queens(N, Qs) :-  
  range(1, N, Ns), 
  queens(Ns, [], Qs).

range(N, N, [N]) :- !.
range(M, N, [M|Ns]) :- 
  M < N, 
  M1 is M+1, 
  range(M1, N, Ns).

queens([], Qs, Qs).
queens(UnplacedQs, SafeQs, Qs) :- 
  select(UnplacedQs, UnplacedQs1,Q),
  not_attack(SafeQs, Q),  
  queens(UnplacedQs1, [Q|SafeQs], Qs).  

not_attack(Xs, X) :- 
  not_attack(Xs, X, 1).
not_attack([], _, _) :- !.
not_attack([Y|Ys], X, N) :-
  X =\= Y+N,  
  X =\= Y-N, 
  N1 is N+1, 
  not_attack(Ys, X, N1).

select([X|Xs], Xs, X).
select([Y|Ys], [Y|Zs], X) :- select(Ys, Zs, X).
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: This isn't remotely a beam search.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. as i understand from your reply the code is not correct. I mean that it is not beam search algorithm. Can you please provide guidelines for correcting the program? I am new in Prolog. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention this problem is a typical *constraint satisfaction problem* and can be efficiency solved using the CSP module of *SWI-Prolog*. Here is the full algorithm:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

queens(N, L) :-
    N #> 0,
    length(L, N),
    L ins 1..N,
    all_different(L),
    applyConstraintOnDescDiag(L),
    applyConstraintOnAscDiag(L),
    label(L).

applyConstraintOnDescDiag([]) :- !.
applyConstraintOnDescDiag([H|T]) :-
    insertConstraintOnDescDiag(H, T, 1),
    applyConstraintOnDescDiag(T).

insertConstraintOnDescDiag(_, [], _) :- !.
insertConstraintOnDescDiag(X, [H|T], N) :-
    H #\= X + N,
    M is N + 1,
    insertConstraintOnDescDiag(X, T, M).

applyConstraintOnAscDiag([]) :- !.
applyConstraintOnAscDiag([H|T]) :-
    insertConstraintOnAscDiag(H, T, 1),
    applyConstraintOnAscDiag(T).

insertConstraintOnAscDiag(_, [], _) :- !.
insertConstraintOnAscDiag(X, [H|T], N) :-
    H #\= X - N,
    M is N + 1,
    insertConstraintOnAscDiag(X, T, M).
```

`N` is the number of queens or the size of the board ([image: N\cdot N]), and [image: L={X_1,\cdots,X_n}], where [image: X_i \in [1,N]], [image: X] being the position of the queen on the line [image: i].

Let's details each part of the algorithm above to understand what happens.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

It indicates to *SWI-Prolog* to load the module containing the predicates for *constraint satisfaction problems*.

```
queens(N, L) :-
        N #> 0,
        length(L, N),
        L ins 1..N,
        all_different(L),
        applyConstraintOnDescDiag(L),
        applyConstraintOnAscDiag(L),
        label(L).
```

The `queens` predicate is the entry point of the algorithm and checks if the terms are properly formatted (number range, length of the list). It checks if the queens are on different lines as well.

```
applyConstraintOnDescDiag([]) :- !.
applyConstraintOnDescDiag([H|T]) :-
    insertConstraintOnDescDiag(H, T, 1),
    applyConstraintOnDescDiag(T).

insertConstraintOnDescDiag(_, [], _) :- !.
insertConstraintOnDescDiag(X, [H|T], N) :-
    H #\= X + N,
    M is N + 1,
    insertConstraintOnDescDiag(X, T, M).
```

It checks if there is a queen on the descendant diagonal of the current queen that is iterated.

```
applyConstraintOnAscDiag([]) :- !.
applyConstraintOnAscDiag([H|T]) :-
    insertConstraintOnAscDiag(H, T, 1),
    applyConstraintOnAscDiag(T).

insertConstraintOnAscDiag(_, [], _) :- !.
insertConstraintOnAscDiag(X, [H|T], N) :-
    H #\= X - N,
    M is N + 1,
    insertConstraintOnAscDiag(X, T, M).
```

Same as previous, but it checks if there is a queen on the ascendant diagonal.

Finally, the results can be found by calling the predicate `queens/2`, such as:

```
?- findall(X, queens(4, X), L).
L = [[2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4, 2]]
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you for posting! There's no need for any `!/0` though. Better keep it general! Argument indexing will automatically distinguish the cases.

Comment: Hello @mat, thanks for your comment ! Indeed they are *green cuts*. I introduced them to prevent performing useless unifications. They can be safely removed. :)

Comment: Please try for example the most general query: Currently, you get for `?- applyConstraintOnDescDiag(Ls).` only the single solution `Ls = []`. This happens because the `!/0` unexpectedly removes solutions that are otherwise correctly reported by this predicate (depending on the instantiation of variables). Thus, these are in fact both *red* cuts: They make your program incomplete! Removing the cuts would make the predicates logically sound and more general, so that you can also use them to *generate* answers.

Comment: In fact, the clauses `applyConstraintOnDescDiag([])` and `applyConstraintOnDescDiag([H|T])` are mutually exclusive. Thus, applying a cut on the first clause only prevent Prolog to unify an empty list to the second clause, which doesn't accept an empty list. The cuts therefore don't modify the behavior of the algorithm, hence they are *green*. I ran the program to find 9 queens. The results is the same as proposed on Wikipedia on the article dedicated to this problem (352). Could you provide me a counter example or more tangible case if you still think they are red cuts ?

Comment: Suppose you know nothing about these predicates. For example, I am a first-time user of Prolog, and I see your definitions. I would like to know more about these predicates. For which terms do these relations hold, what are they describing? So my first query is the most general one, in which I ask Prolog: What do solutions look like *at all*? I try: `?- applyConstraintOnDescDiag(Ls).`. In response, I get *only*: `Ls = []`. So this only describes the empty list? No! Because when I add `Ls = [_,_]` before the query, it *also* succeeds! This shows that this cut is *red*: It *removes* solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, the algorithm you're trying to implement is a simple depth-first search rather than beam search. That's ok, because it should be (I don't see how beam search will be effective for this problem and it can be hard to program).

I'm not going to debug this code for you, but I will give you a suggestion: build the chess board bottom-up with

```
queens(0, []).
queens(N, [Q|Qs]) :-
    M is N-1,
    queens(M, Qs),
    between(1, N, Q),
    safe(Q, Qs).
```

where `safe(Q,Qs)` is true iff none of `Qs` attack `Q`. `safe/2` is then the conjunction of a simple `memberchk/2` check (see SWI-Prolog manual) and your `not_attack/2` predicate, which on first sight seems to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

A quick check on [Google](http://www.google.com) has [found](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=prolog+n-queens+problem) a [few](http://okmij.org/ftp/Prolog/QueensProblem.prl) [candidates](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~rdaniels/html/courses/Coen171/NQProlog.htm) for you to [compare](http://www.javaist.com/blog/2008/11/06/eight-queens-problem-in-proglog/) with your code and find what to change.

My favoured solution for sheer clarity would be the second of the ones linked to above:

```
% This program finds a solution to the 8 queens problem.  That is, the problem of placing 8
% queens on an 8x8 chessboard so that no two queens attack each other.  The prototype
% board is passed in as a list with the rows instantiated from 1 to 8, and a corresponding
% variable for each column.  The Prolog program instantiates those column variables as it
%  finds the solution.

% Programmed by Ron Danielson, from an idea by Ivan Bratko.

% 2/17/00


queens([]).                                 % when place queen in empty list, solution found

queens([ Row/Col | Rest]) :-                % otherwise, for each row
            queens(Rest),                   % place a queen in each higher numbered row
            member(Col, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]), % pick one of the possible column positions
            safe( Row/Col, Rest).           % and see if that is a safe position
                                            % if not, fail back and try another column, until
                                            % the columns are all tried, when fail back to
                                            % previous row

safe(Anything, []).                         % the empty board is always safe

safe(Row/Col, [Row1/Col1 | Rest]) :-        % see if attack the queen in next row down
            Col =\= Col1,                   % same column?
            Col1 - Col =\= Row1 - Row,      % check diagonal
            Col1 - Col =\= Row - Row1,
            safe(Row/Col, Rest).            % no attack on next row, try the rest of board

member(X, [X | Tail]).                      % member will pick successive column values

member(X, [Head | Tail]) :-
            member(X, Tail).

board([1/C1, 2/C2, 3/C3, 4/C4, 5/C5, 6/C6, 7/C7, 8/C8]). % prototype board
```

The final link, however, solves it in three different ways so you can compare against three known solutions.